# Linking C++ to static library; undefined reference errors

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I'm trying to link a small C++ test program, `main.o` to a 3rd party static library, but get some inexplicable `undefined reference` errors.

Specifically:

```
g++  -o secoTest -lpthread  main.o  libEAPI.a
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x29fe): undefined reference to `EApiWDog_SetConfigAndStart(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x33fc): undefined reference to `EApiSetCarrier(unsigned char)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3956): more undefined references to `EApiSetCarrier(unsigned char)' follow
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x3965): undefined reference to `EApiGPIOGetSerialCfg(unsigned char*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3a0a): undefined reference to `EApiSetCarrier(unsigned char)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3a19): undefined reference to `EApiGPIOSetSerialCfg(unsigned char)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3adf): undefined reference to `EApiFanEnable(unsigned int, unsigned char)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3b83): undefined reference to `EApiFanDisable()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, it seems the symbols **are** present in the library. For example:

```
nm --demangle libEAPI.a | grep EApiFanDisable
00003c20 T EApiFanDisable
```

The strange thing is the symbols are not **exactly** the same. In `main.o` it is

```
nm --demangle main.o | grep EApiFanDisable
         U EApiFanDisable()
```

So one has `()` and one doesn't.

Similarily,

```
nm --demangle main.o | grep EApiSetCarrier
         U EApiSetCarrier(unsigned char)
nm --demangle libEAPI.a | grep EApiSetCarrier
000015d0 T EApiSetCarrier
```

If I leave out the library altogether from the command line (eg, `g++  -o secoTest -lpthread  main.o`) it shows lots of errors as expected.

`main.o` references external symbols with and with `()` [why?]:

```
     U EApiVgaSetBacklightEnable
     U EApiWDogStart
     U EApiWDogTrigger
     U EApiFanEnable(unsigned int, unsigned char)
     U EApiFanDisable()
     U EApiSetCarrier(unsigned char)
```

But the library has only symbols without `()` [why?]:

```
000020e0 T EApiVgaSetBacklightEnable
000024e0 T EApiWDogStart
000026f0 T EApiWDogTrigger
00003c20 T EApiFanDisable
00003bf0 T EApiFanEnable
000015d0 T EApiSetCarrier
```

Would that be the reason for the undefined references?   How would I fix it?  Not sure where to look next...

(I cannot modify the 3rd party library but have the header files.)

**EDIT**

As lisyarus suggested, here is the `nm` without the `--demangle`.  Indeed, the symbols are different.  The g++ compiler (v4.4.7) generates a mangled symbol *for some symbols only* while the library always has plain symbols...  [why?]

```
nm libEAPI.a main.o | grep EApiWDogTrigger
000026f0 T EApiWDogTrigger
         U EApiWDogTrigger
nm libEAPI.a main.o | grep EApiSetCarrier
000015d0 T EApiSetCarrier
         U _Z14EApiSetCarrierh
```

Comment: What does `nm` without demangling show? It may happen that the library was compiled with a different compiler / standard / etc, and the mangled names are somehow different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The library `libEAPI.a` contains object files compiled in `C`, not `C++`.
The symbols therefore have not been name-mangled and cannot serve to
resolve the name-mangled function references generated by your C++
code.

Run:

```
nm libEAPI.a | grep EApiFanDisable
```

and you will see no change.

Run:

```
nm main.o | grep EApiFanDisable
```

and you will see the mangled symbol, which is neither `EApiFanDisable` nor `EApiFanDisable()`
but something more like `_Z14EApiFanDisablev`, that the linker is actually trying
to resolve.

To avoid these linkage errors you must inform your C++ compiler, when it
compiles the header file(s) of `libEAPI`, that the declarations therein have
external C linkage, so it will emit unmangled references to the symbols declared: like so:

**main.cpp**

```
...
extern "C" {
#include "EAPI.h"   // or whatever
}

...
```

BTW, this commandline:

```
g++  -o secoTest -lpthread  main.o  libEAPI.a
```

will fail to link `libpthread` on a Debian-based distro (Ubuntu et al)
more recent than Debian 6, as all libraries must be linked in dependency order since then:

```
g++  -o secoTest main.o  libEAPI.a -lpthread
```

Even better, do not use the non-portable `-lpthread` and pass the portable
option `-pthread` for both compilation and linkage. It means: *Do whatever
is right to compile/link with Posix Threads support*

Comment: Very insightful, thanks for the valuable information :)